# Use Leibnitz Theorem to solve the following-

Tags: integration, leibniz-integral-rule

[image]

If anyone could break it down to smaller steps, I'd appreciate alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
F(a)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}(1-e^{-ax})\,dx. \tag{1}
$$
Differentiating $F$ with respect to $a$, we obtain
$$
F'(a)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}xe^{-ax}\,dx =\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(1+a)x}\,dx
=\frac{1}{1+a}. \tag{2}
$$
Now we integrate $(2)$ with respect to $a$:
$$
F(a)=\int\frac{da}{1+a}=\ln(1+a)+C. \tag{3}
$$
To determine $C$, we notice that the integral $(1)$ vanishes for $a=0$, so
$$
F(0)=0=\ln(1+0)+C\implies C=0. \tag{4}
$$
Therefore, we conclude that
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}(1-e^{-ax})\,dx=\ln(1+a)\qquad(a>-1). \tag{5}
$$